# changing the pixel color of imageview

Tags: android

i have to change the color of just one pixel of an selected image from gallery 
i used a button to change this pixel but always the application has forced to stop when i clicked the button
plz help me to solve this problem :(
this is my button code

```
public void btnClick2 (View v){
     bmp.setPixel(30,30,0xFF000000 );
}
```

and this is onactivityresult code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == SELECTED_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
{
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();


  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);



  iv1.setImageBitmap(bmp);


}
```

}

Comment: You should give more details on the type of error you have received.

Comment: when i clicked the button ,the applicaation is forced to close "unfortunately app has stopped"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does force close because `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` returns an immutable `Bitmap`, while `setPixel` works only on mutable bitmaps. You can use [Bitmap.copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29) to get a mutable version of the original bitmap.

Edit:

```
Bitmap tmpBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
bmp = tmpBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 ,true);
```

Comment: sorry but where can i use Bitmap.copy ? can you help me with part of code i shuld change ? thznks alot

Comment: if it does crash, post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: there is an error in   bmp = tmpBmp.copy(new BitmapFactory.Options(), true);
   instruction

Comment: I did update the answer. Have you seen the edit? Did it work?